# How to debug a non-packed Microsoft Edge extension with Native Messaging Host?

Tags: microsoft-edge, chrome-native-messaging

Couple days ago MS released the Native Messaging support in the MS Edge.
I've tried to debug the already working Chrome-based extension which uses Native Messaging Host under MS Edge and it failed with error: "Native Messaging not supported for non-packaged extension".
There are no documentation about Native Messaging manifest registration (I mean the registry key), the format of the manifest file (everyone knows that NMH manifest for Chrome & Firefox is a little different). When this documentation will be available?
And how can I debug the unpacked extension with NMH under MS Edge?

Answer (score 0):

[The official document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/extensions/guides/native-messaging/) give the explanation for the error "Native Messaging not supported for non-packaged extension".

> The Edge extension platform restricts the native messaging host to being a UWP app that is packaged in the same AppX as the extension.

NMH for Edge must be an Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app which register an [AppService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.appservice.aspx).
NMH for Chrome/Firefox is not supported because the communication protocol of Edge's native messaging is totally different.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a little, but not 100%.
I've created a UWP app with AppService inside it according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service. Then add extension to AppX folder, modify the appxmanifest file, pack and sign with temp certificate. Then installed the extension to the Edge (just run and click Install). After clicking the Launch button - looks like UWP app is run as a standalone one.

Comment: When trying to connect to the UWP app using chrome.runtime.connectNative() I got this error: "App with AppService "com.microsoft.inventory" and PackageFamilyName "MY_PFN" is unavailable."